# How to avoid terraform error "retrieving" in CD?

Tags: terraform, azure-synapse

I am deploying Azure Synapse with Terraform in Azure DevOps.

When task "Terraform plan" is called I have the following error:

```
   2024-01-19T14:54:54.6888139Z [1mPlan:[0m 1 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
2024-01-19T14:54:54.6888458Z [0m[31m╷[0m[0m
2024-01-19T14:54:54.6889158Z [31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mretrieving File System "metadata" in Storage Account "adlsplatformdev": datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded[0m
2024-01-19T14:54:54.6889625Z [31m│[0m [0m
2024-01-19T14:54:54.6890071Z [31m│[0m [0m[0m  with module.data_warehouse.azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.synapse_metadata,
2024-01-19T14:54:54.6890754Z [31m│[0m [0m  on ../modules/data_warehouse/workspace.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "synapse_metadata":
2024-01-19T14:54:54.6891304Z [31m│[0m [0m   1: resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "synapse_metadata" [4m{[0m[0m
2024-01-19T14:54:54.6891621Z [31m│[0m [0m
2024-01-19T14:54:54.6891855Z [31m╵[0m[0m
2024-01-19T14:54:54.7558142Z ##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: TerraformPlanFailed
2024-01-19T14:54:54.7566721Z ##[error]Error: TerraformPlanFailed 1
2024-01-19T14:54:54.7569026Z ##[section]Finishing: Terraform - Plan
```

I don't understand these error. I have deleted synapse manually in azure portal.

Datalake has private endpoint.

How can I solve this ? Deployment failed because of there error.

Comment: Make sure that the Data Lake and other related resources in Azure DevOps can be accessed and managed by the Azure service principal or managed identity that Terraform uses. Then, execute the command `terraform refresh`. This is necessary because some resources were manually deleted in the portal. We need to synchronize the state with the current infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to avoid the terraform error "retrieving" which in general occurs when the existing configuration in the state miss matches with the state.

A possible cause of the error you are experiencing when you try to deploy Azure Synapse with Terraform in Azure DevOps is that the Terraform AzureRM provider cannot access or retrieve the properties of the File System "metadata" in your Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) account. This part of the error message indicates the problem: "retrieving File System "metadata" in Storage Account "adlsplatformdev": datalakestore. Client#GetProperties: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded".

1. **Authentication/Authorization Issues**: If Terraform cannot access the Data Lake, it might be due to insufficient permissions. Check that the service principal or managed identity that Terraform uses has the appropriate roles and permissions.
2. **Resource Deletion**: If you removed resources (such as Synapse) from the Azure portal by yourself, your Terraform state may not match the real Azure environment. You can try running `terraform refresh` to fix the state.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demovksb-rg"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "demovkdatalakestore"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  is_hns_enabled           = true
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
  name               = "metadata"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Now when we delete the metadata container in the portal

[image]

Then there will be a miss match with the state file with existing infra there is a conflict needs to be addressed for the terraform by

[image]

Resources in Terraform can depend on each other. If you delete a resource that other resources rely on, you might encounter unexpected problems. For instance, suppose your Terraform configuration has some resources or settings that require the Synapse workspace to exist. In that case, deleting the Synapse workspace could break these dependencies and cause errors when Terraform attempts to access or modify the dependent resources.